# Remove link in NSString

Tags: iphone, xcode, string, nsstring

I want to delete a part of my NSString.
I have this one : `@"Test Hello http://www.google.fr wolrd"`
And I want to have in output :  `@"Test Hello other world"`

Some ideas?
Thx :)

Comment: `[yourString stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString:@"http://google.fr" withString:@"other"];`

Comment: don't forget `[yourString stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString:@"wolrd" withString:@"world"];` ;-)

Comment: My string could be http://google.fr but also an other one like http://facebook.fr or http://twitter.fr or whatever...

Comment: so is the string always host.tld? It'll be difficult to remove an arbitrary "whatever" string.

Comment: I have just to remove a url in my string.

Comment: There is no such thing as "just removing a url in my string".

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NSDataDetector` to search the string for any links (per Apple's formulas of course).

```
NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
```

Then you can use `stringByReplacingMatchesInString:options:range:withTemplate:` to replace all the links with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use RegexKitLite like regex library to filter any URL from the string using methods like `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex`.